# Show that $\binom{n}{3} = \binom{n-1}{2} + \binom{n-1}{3}$

Tags: combinatorics

Show that $\binom{n}{3} = \binom{n-1}{2} + \binom{n-1}{3}$

My solution

Formula:
$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

$LHS = \binom{n}{3} = \frac{n!}{3*2(n-3)!} = \frac{n(n-1)!}{3*2(n-3)(n-4)!} = $

$ = \frac{(n-1)!}{3*2(n-4)!}*\frac{n}{n-3} = \binom{n-1}{3} * \frac{n}{n-3} $

So i got one term right. Anyone know how i could continue from here? :)

Comment: It'd be easier to start with RHS.

Comment: I realize now that maybe Pascal's rule is very useful here? Or maybe not

Comment: Yeah, it's direct from the property of Pascal's triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\binom n3 = \binom{n-1}{2}+\binom{n-1}{3}\\
\frac{n!}{6(n-3)!} = \frac{(n-1)!}{2(n-3)!}+\frac{(n-1)!}{6(n-4)!}\\
\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6} = \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{6}\\
n = 3 + n - 3\\
n=n$
Hence proved.
In the second last step, I multiplied by $\frac{6}{(n-1)(n-2)}$

Comment: Hey Daniel, please upvote and/or accept my answer by clicking on the tick mark to the left of my answer. It really helps out a lot man...

Comment: Thank you sir! I dont understand that last part. How is $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6} $ equal to $ \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2} +\frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{6}$

Comment: Think of the expansion of the factorials in its true product form in the numerator and denominator and then see how many terms cancel out.

Comment: For example, in the LHS, $(n-3)!$ in the denominator is nothing but a factor of$n!$ in the numerator.

Comment: Thank you so much for up voting and accepting my answer

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Prove that $$\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}=\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}+\frac{(n-1)(n-2)(n -3)}{6}$$